# Как узнать где вызывается метод?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, отладка

Есть проект на java, он огромный, перерыть весь код нереально. Есть метод который отрабатывает больше раз чем нужно, очевидно его кто-то когда-то добавил в ненужном (на данный момент) месте. Как узнать откуда он вызывается?

Метод вполне распространенный, простой поиск по тексту не поможет, и если искать как метод, то "237 usage".

Могу в самом методе поставить бряк, но назад же по нему не прошагать.

Среда разработки IntelliJ IDEA 12

Comment: А что, в java действительно нет возможности посмотреть stack traceback из самого этого метода?

Comment: наверное я не знаю про него,
он должен быть в идее, буду искать..

Comment: А почему бы вам не воспользоваться профайлером?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно в коде метода писать в лог или консоль стектрейс (его можно получить вызвав метод [`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace())).

**UPD**

Если хотите проанализироовать цепочку вызовов метода средствами IDE, то в IDEA есть фича [Call Hierarchy](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/building-call-hierarchy.html).

Comment: спасибо! пошел курить тулзу.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getCallerClassAndMethodName() {
        StackTraceElement[] tracer;
        tracer = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
        if (tracer.length>2 ) {return tracer[2].getClassName()+"#"+tracer[2].getMethodName();}
        else return null;
}
```

Использовал StackTraceElement[]
Метод возвращает строку в формате Class#Name содержащую вызвавший класс и его метод, или null, если вызова извне не было.

Comment: Код без пояснений, как его использовать малополезен отвечающему. Попробуйте добавить поясняющий текст.